# Assistance with: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE users (       
    username VARCHAR(50),
    password CHAR(32),
    email VARCHAR(255),
    english_name VARCHAR(100),
    arabic_name VARCHAR(100),
    GENDER VARCHAR(9),
    Nationality VARCHAR(255),
    BirthDate DATE,
    phone VARCHAR(20),
    Date_of_contract DATE,
    Salary_number INT (25),
    PRIMARY KEY(username),
    check(GENDER in ('Male', 'Female'))
);
```

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

I want to know where is the error?

Comment: Please don't tag unrelated RDBMS... the error looks like Oracle, so please remove MySQL and SQL Server.

Comment: `INT` doesn't have a precision.

Comment: Using `char()` is almost always the wrong choice. Use `varchar` instead - as you did with the other character columns. And there is no secret performance or storage improvement when using a limit of 255 compared to a value greater than 255

Comment: Remove all the declaration lines. 1. Begin adding declarations line by line unless you have an error. 2. Then check [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-TABLE.html), what was wrong with the last added line. 3. Correct your code and go to step 1.

Comment: `users` is a bad table name for most of the databases

Answer (score 0):

Don't specify the width of an integer value, just **INT**

```
CREATE TABLE users ( 
    username VARCHAR(50),     
    password CHAR(32),     
    email VARCHAR(255),     
    english_name VARCHAR(100),     
    arabic_name VARCHAR(100),
    GENDER VARCHAR(9),     
    Nationality VARCHAR(255),     
    BirthDate DATE,     
    phone VARCHAR(20),     
    Date_of_contract DATE,
    Salary_number INT,     
    PRIMARY KEY(username),     
    check(GENDER in ('Male', 'Female'))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the size then use NUMBER (25).

```
CREATE TABLE users (       
    username VARCHAR(50),
    password CHAR(32),
    email VARCHAR(255),
    english_name VARCHAR(100),
    arabic_name VARCHAR(100),
    GENDER VARCHAR(9),
    Nationality VARCHAR(255),
    BirthDate DATE,
    phone VARCHAR(20),
    Date_of_contract DATE,
    Salary_number NUMBER (25),
    PRIMARY KEY(username),
    check(GENDER in ('Male', 'Female'))
);
```